# not having acess to all methods ( or referencing a method in XAML fails)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

In my WPF application, user can select a command by doing a right click. Now, I have created a button and want to associate this method to the button.

What I have done so far:

In the XAML  file I have:

`<Button Content="Run Compare" Command="{x:Static RunCompare_Exectued}"></Button>`

Then in ResourceDirectory section I am trying to give a reference to my file holding the method as

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:myMethods="**Nothing Comes up here!!!**"
                    >
```

Usually I would hold *Ctrl and hit the space* bar but nothing shows up then I tried to type clr-namespace:FileNameConatiningMethod ... yet I'm getting error as:

**Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Application.Commands' that is not included in the assembly.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have access to one of the files which has method A and B, however, I don't have access to method C and D in a different source file. Shouldn't this be OK by adding Namespace in the root tag of the XAML file?

let's say my namespace is ABC so I have:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:ABC">
```

Comment: but even if the CLR stuff does not appears... does it work if you type manually your namespace?

Comment: You can find information about how to format the namespace [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx).

Comment: @@Juan, no even I tried to do it manually it did not like it.

Comment: @@Brian, I have tried this `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyNameSpaceName>`  is this wrong?

Comment: Can you use your page tag to put your reference? xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=DemoAssembly"> for this purposes

Answer (score 0):

Please check your approach against this one I found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547.aspx).

Please also check that your code is compiling and there are no assembly reference conflicts.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

  <!-- String resource that can be localized -->
  <system:String x:Key="localizedMessage">en-US Message</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>

<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="StringResources.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: yes it compiles but again I had to type system namespace manually however, got compiled.

Comment: xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:yournamespace;assembly=yourassembly" try something like this and replace with your data. Let me know